How would those who subscribe to Restrictivism interpret John 5:28-29?
When I read John 5:24-29 (CSB)

24 "Truly I tell you, anyone who hears my word and believes him who sent me has eternal life and will not come under judgment but has passed from death to life.
25 "Truly I tell you, an hour is coming, and is now here, when the dead will hear the voice of the Son of God, and those who hear will live.  For just as the Father has life in himself, so also he has granted to the Son to have life in himself.
And he has granted him the right to pass judgment, because he is the Son of Man.  28 Do not be amazed at this, because a time is coming when all who are in the graves will hear his voice and come out—those who have done good things, to the resurrection of life, but those who have done wicked things, to the resurrection of condemnation.

it seems clear that Jesus will evangelize the dead who hasn't heard the gospel, and that there is an element of consideration of how one conducts one's life before death.
Restrictivism can be defined as: "God does not provide salvation to those who fail to hear of Jesus and come to faith in him before they die."  How would those who believe Restrictivism (see sample adherents in the chart below) interpret that verse?

(Source of the chart: What About Those Who Have Never Heard?  Three Views on the Destiny of the Unevangelized)

Do you recommend that book? It is an issue I would be interested to learn more about. I lean towards Restricitvism or Universal Opportunity, but I some people I respect deeply are Inclusivist.

@DarkMalthorp I have only skimmed the book, but I read of other views through Christian theology / philosophy books, rather than considering each option exegetically (as what this book does, since the book series main audience is evangelicals).  Basically I recommend all of the Spectrum Multiview series as well as Zondervan's Counterpoint series, if only to broaden one's horizon of legitimate options of interpreting the Bible; "legitimate" since the series exclude gross misuse of the verses (like prosperity gospel, new age, etc.).  Help us to be more gracious to other denominations.

Thanks, I may take a look. The reviews on Amazon suggest that they didn't do a good job defending Restricitvism (which is probably fine for me since that's the view I'm most familiar with anyway)

@DarkMalthorp Maybe the corresponding book Four Views on Salvation in a Pluralistic World is better, which is from a generally newer Zondervan Counterpoint series, although that book is only a year newer.

Ah, yes that one seems very well-reviewed. I shall add it to my list! Thanks again.

The simplest answer is that nothing in the cited passages says that the resurrected ones are hearing the gospel; while the dead do "hear his voice" in v.28, in v.29 there is no evangelism or conversion, only judgment on the basis of works. In the resurrection at the end of time, the final judgment is pronounced based on people's conduct. That much is clear from this verse. C.f. the very similar judgment scene in Revelation 20:11-15 and Romans 2:6-10.
However, nothing in this contradicts Restrictivism, which you define as "God does not provide salvation to those who fail to hear of Jesus and come to faith in him before they die." We need to be careful how we define "salvation". What are people being saved from? It is, of course, our sins and their just condemnation. If someone is judged righteous on the basis of their works, that is not salvation.
The other two passages (Revelation 20 and Romans 2) both make clear the point that if anyone is judged on the basis of their works, they will not be counted righteous. That's not because the works-judgment is rigged, but rather because we are sinners and the judgment is just:

For all who have sinned without the law will also perish without the law, and all who sinned under the law will be judged by the law. (Romans 2:12)

Combine this with Romans 3:22, and we see that no-one is actually counted righteous by their works. This is not because the works-judgment is a blanket "you are damned", but rather because the works that people actually do are worthy of condemnation.
Similarly, Revelation 20 says

And I saw the dead, great and small, standing before the throne, and books were opened. Then another book was opened, which is the book of life. And the dead were judged by what was written in the books, according to what they had done...And if anyone's name was not found written in the book of life, he was thrown into the lake of fire.
(Rev 20:12, 15)

We see all people being judged according to their works. However, it is only those whose names are in the book of life who are not condemned. The book of life (which is a ledger of the saved, c.f. Luke 10:20) is carefully distinguished from the books which record people's deeds. While this passage and Romans 2:6-11 and John 5:28-29 affirm the theoretical possibility that someone judged on the basis of works would enter heaven if their works were righteous, Revelation 20:15 tells us that no-one actually achieves that. The ESV Study Bible footnote explains: "All whose names are 'not found written in the book of life' will be condemned for the record of their deeds" (emph. in original).
So, the works-based judgment of those who never heard the Gospel does not contradict Restrictivism.
Returning to John 5, if we look back a few verses, we find a statement that seems (to my eye) to point towards Restrictivism:

Truly, truly, I say to you, an hour is coming, and is now here, when the dead will hear the voice of the Son of God, and those who hear will live. (v.25)

It is the ones who hear who live. Augustine also saw this passage as teaching Restrictivism (City of God XX.6). The whole section is too long to quote in its entirety here, but I'll proffer some excerpts sufficient to show I'm not misrepresenting him:

By "those who hear" he means those who obey, believe, and persevere to the end.


All without exception are dead in sin, whether in original sin or in the voluntary sin that is added to it, due either to not knowing or to knowing and not doing what is just.


By taking part in the first resurrection, that is, by which one passes from death to life in the present, he will not come under that condemnation which Christ signified by using the word "judgment".


"And those who have done evil to the resurrection of judgment"; these are the ones who will not live, because they are the ones who are going to die the second death. They have done evil because their lives have been evil, and their lives have been evil because they did not rise in the first resurrection, the resurrection of the soul, which now is, or because, after they had risen, they did not endure to the end.


[The first resurrection] takes place in faith and happens now through baptism.

(Quotes from the translation by William Babcock.)

Postscript: It's important not to misinterpret Restrictivism as teaching that the last judgment is a quiz with one question, i.e. "Did you believe that Jesus is your savior and lord?" People are surely not held accountable for rejecting Jesus if they never heard the message of the Gospel. On the contrary, people are judged on the basis of all their deeds. Since we all do unrighteous things, everyone is judged guilty by this standard. It is only those who receive the grace of Christ who are saved. The question of Restrictivism vs. Inclusivism and the other positions mentioned is not whether anyone is righteous enough to merit an inheritance in Heaven, but rather whether the grace of Christ can possibly be received by those who haven't heard the message.

On the surface looks like you cover the bases, hence the +1.  I'll read it some more later (including fact checking the Augustine quote)  before giving feedback in comments or accept it (check mark).  Thanks.  I'll also investigate alternate meanings of John 5:24-5:29.

Thanks. Based on all I've read, it seems pretty standard to see v.25 as talking about the spiritual resurrection, c.f. Eph. 2:1-7. I'd be interested to hear if some prominent theologians see it otherwise though.

Is "whoever hears" referencing the physical auditory act or is it a hearing with acceptance?  Sort of the opposite of Matthew 13:13-14.

It is surely the latter in John 5:25, unless you think that merely being evangelized to is sufficient for salvation.
